# systemd waiting too long for network at Debian 8.0 Jessie's boot

Tags: debian, networking, boot, systemd, upgrade

My system has booted up relatively fast while ran Debian 7 Wheezy, but after an upgrade to Debian 8 Jessie, and therefore from `SysVinit` to `systemd`, it became a way, way slower.

The thing slowing down the booting is network. The waiting for the upbringing of network interfaces exceeds 1 minute. I don't know what in the `/etc/network/interfaces` is affecting the boot up process, so here it is in its entirety.

**/etc/network/interfaces**:

```
allow-auto lo
        iface lo inet loopback

auto wlan0
        iface wlan0 inet static
                address 192.168.150.1
                netmask 255.255.255.0

auto eth1
        iface eth1 inet manual
                up ifconfig $IFACE 0.0.0.0 up
                down ifconfig $IFACE down

auto eth2
        iface eth2 inet manual
                up ifconfig $IFACE 0.0.0.0 up
                down ifconfig $IFACE down

auto eth0
        iface eth0 inet dhcp
                post-up brctl addbr br0
                post-up brctl addif br0 eth1 eth2
                post-up ifconfig br0 192.168.10.1
                pre-down ifconfig br0 0.0.0.0
                pre-down brctl delif br0 eth1 eth2
                pre-down ifconfig br0 down
                pre-down brctl delbr br0
```

Any suggestions how to boost things?

Comment: Actually I had issues where multiple services like samba, bind or lighttpd don't wait for network to be ready and start right away causing interface binding issues...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The solution is fairly easy, just replace `auto` to `allow-hotplug`. So I ended up with this:

```
allow-hotplug lo
        iface lo inet loopback

allow-hotplug wlan0
        iface wlan0 inet static
                address 192.168.150.1
                netmask 255.255.255.0

allow-hotplug eth1
        iface eth1 inet manual
                up ifconfig $IFACE 0.0.0.0 up
                down ifconfig $IFACE down

allow-hotplug eth2
        iface eth2 inet manual
                up ifconfig $IFACE 0.0.0.0 up
                down ifconfig $IFACE down

allow-hotplug eth0
        iface eth0 inet dhcp
                post-up brctl addbr br0
                post-up brctl addif br0 eth1 eth2
                post-up ifconfig br0 192.168.10.1
                pre-down ifconfig br0 0.0.0.0
                pre-down brctl delif br0 eth1 eth2
                pre-down ifconfig br0 down
                pre-down brctl delbr br0
```

Now system boots really fast.

Comment: My interfaces are managef by network manager, this file is almost empty, still looking.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem and the file names are slightly different.

Under /etc/network/interfaces.d (Note the .d) in the folder name.  Inside the folder is the file "setup" which I changed "auto eth0" to "allow-hotplug eth0"

That seems to have worked:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```